# How can I create this graphic in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I want to create a 3d box, with a grid overlaid on the surface of the box, and have the grid have the same vanishing points. How do I do this? I am very new to InkScape.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Is the example what you want to achieve, or is it your failed attempt? Also note that Inkscape has very limited 3D capabilities. You might be better doing this in actual 3D software such as Blender, which is also free and open source.

Comment: Tiled boxes like these https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBeSc.png are easy to draw. There's no vanishing points because this is a parallel projection, there's no perspective. Can you accept it or should it be a perspective drawing? Know that if it must have a perspective and vanishing points, drawing equally sized boxes right in a 2D graphic program really needs descriptive geometry knowledge and then some more, if the boxes must be cubes.

Comment: (continued) This box https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ZSA.png is built of equally sized cubes and drawn in 3D. The perspective makes every cube different. Drawing this right in Inkscape would be a nightmare, but it's not impossible. Mathematicians explored the math behind the construction hundreds years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape has a dedicated tool for creating 3d boxes ([image: Box Icon] or <kbd>Shift + F4</kbd> by default). I've found that it's really finicky and buggy, though.

Anyway, draw a box on the canvas, make all angles in the toolbar parallel and set them to something like X: 185 Y: 270 Z: 350 (or X: 175 Y: 90 Z: 10 in older verions). Adjust your box with the diamond-shaped handles.

Switch to the selection tool, select your box and set a stroke in the 'Fill and Stroke' dialog, or select some of its faces with the node-editing tool and set the fill color.

Enable snapping, snapping to nodes and snapping to cusp nodes in the snapping toolbar. Now make a clone of your box with <kbd>Alt + D</kbd> (duplicates seem to constantly lose their perspective information) and drag it next to your original box until it snaps two corners together. Repeat until you have the amount of boxes in the shape you want. You may have to adjust the z-order with the 'raise' and 'lower' buttons in the toolbar.